# Dataproc bdutil versioning

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

Is possible to set [hadoop cluster image version](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/setting-up-a-hadoop-cluster) using the `bdutil` command-line tool?

Using the WebUI console or GCloud is possible to chose image version 1.0 which supports Hadoop 2.x and Hive 1.2. In contrast, using `bdutil`, according to the documentation is not possible to deploy Hadoop 2.x with Pig and Hive.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, bdutil does not use the same VM images as Dataproc and as a result changing deployed software versions isn't as simple as changing a --image-version flag.

The current pig and hive support in bdutil is provided by the extensions in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/tree/master/extensions/querytools and could theoretically be modified to deploy new versions of pig or hive.